# Show that $f$ is measurable with respect to $L$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $(R,L, λ)$ be the Lebesgue measure space and $f : R → R$ a function with $f(x) = 127e^x$
for all $x ∈ Q^c$. Show that $f$ is measurable with respect to $L$.

This is a question on a past exam paper for a measure theory course I'm taking and it has me stumped.

I'm thinking I might need to bring in a function $g$ and then prove that since $g$ is measurable then so is $f$ but I'm not quite sure. A push in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By $Q$ you mean the rational numbers?

Comment: Hint: what is the measure of $Q$? Is $Q^c$ measurable? If so, what is its measure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $Q$ is the set of rational numbers, you are given that $f$ is equal almost everywhere to a continuous function, and is therefore measurable.

Can you prove that if $g$ is measurable, $f$ is a function, and $\lambda(\{f \not= g\}) = 0$, then $f$ is measurable too?